# How to cancel click event of container div trigger when click elements which inside container in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, events

E.g

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inside">I am not fire when click me</div>
</div>

$('.container').click(function(){
  // container do something here
});
```

but,when I click the div inside it also trigger the container's click event because the div is inside the container, so , I need a way to prevent the container event trigger when I click on the inside div!

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a more general solution, you should check [`e.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) in `container`'s `click` event handler.

```
$('.container').click(function(e) {
   // If you want to ignore clicks to anything inside the `.container` div:
   if (!$(e.target).hasClass('container')) return;
   // or, if you only want the `.inside` div to not fire the event,
   if ($(e.target).hasClass('inside')) return;

   // container do something here
});
```

This way you're not preventing propagation of the event, which would break bound [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handlers.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

```
$('.inside').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

That should work for you. It stops any click in the inside div from bubbling up to the container.

Here's a quick example as well - http://jsfiddle.net/Yf8Ra/1/

Comment: No. `stopPropagation()` is generally a bad idea, and is specifically the wrong thing to do in this case: https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Answer (score 1):

Add a click event handler to inside as follows:

```
$('.inside').click(function(event) {
    // do anything you might want with the click for inside
    return false; // prevents click event from bubbling up the DOM hierarchy
});
```

Alternatively, `event.stopPropagation()`  also prevents bubbling like so:

```
$('.inside').click(function(event) {
    // do anything you might want with the click for inside
    event.stopPropagation(); // prevents click event from bubbling up the DOM hierarchy
});
```

[This article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) explains event bubbling.

Comment: the click event didn't work for me,and mousedown event work fine,but when I drag and move the inside div[draggable plugin applied],the container event trigger again

Comment: @qinHaiXiang - did you check and see what the target of the event was when it got to the container, as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092675/how-to-cancel-click-event-of-container-div-trigger-when-click-elements-which-insi/5092899#5092899)?  Was it the inside div or the container div?