# how to assign different behavior to parent and child elements when child is hovering on top of parent?

Tags: javascript, css, event-handling, onclick, overlays

## Long story short

Please see the demo [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8743819/reducedtestcase/overlaysandclickevents/src/dooverlay.html).

I have several `div.story-in-myworks`

inside each `div.story-in-myworks`, there is a `div.pageimage-div-overlay` that controls the overlay over each `div.story-in-myworks`.

Inside each `div.pageimage-div-overlay` there is a `a.btn-storysetting` responsible for hiding and showing a `div.storysettings_talkbubble_left`.

both `a.btn-storysetting` and `div.storysettings_talkbubble_left` are child elements of `div.pageimage-div-overlay`.

Here is a snippet:

```
<div class="img-holder story-in-myworks " rel="91" style="background: url('img/01d-0.jpg?1353745136') no-repeat; background-size: cover; border: 1px solid #DCDDDE">
            <div class="pageimage-div-overlay">
                <a class="btn-storysetting" href="#"><span></span></a>
                <div class="storysettings_talkbubble_left settings-bubble border-radius-5 hidden talkbubble-padding">
```

The basic issue is I want a different behavior when I click on div.story-in-myworks OR div.pageimage-div-overlay which does NOT affect the click event handler for `a.btn-storysetting`

## What I wanted to accomplish

1. when cursor moves into any single `div.story-in-myworks`, an overlay appears over that `div` **(done)**
2. when cursor moves into any single `div.story-in-myworks`, an image (`btn-storysetting12x12.png`) appears at the top right hand corner **(done)**
3. when left click on the `btn-storysetting12x12.png`, a bubble appears right next to the image. **(done)**
4. when the bubble appears, the selected `div.story-in-myworks` continues to exhibit the overlay look **(done)**
5. After the bubble appears and then left click anywhere else in the doc, the bubble closes and `div.story-in-myworks` goes back to normal without the overlay **(done)**
6. After the bubble appears, cursor can leave the bubble and the bubble stay visible and the overlay for the selected `div.story-in-myworks` remains. **(done)**
7. When a bubble is opened for 1 `div.story-in-myworks` and then cursor opens the `btn-storysetting12x12.png` of ANOTHER `div.story-in-myworks`, the previous bubble disappears and the corresponding overlay is hidden, but the currently selected `div` now has the overlay and the bubble appears for the currently selected `div` **(done)**
8. Without changing any of the previous 7 behavior, I want to be able to click on the `div.story-in-myworks` which leads to another behavior e.g., navigating to another webpage.

Note that those marked **(done)** are accomplished. Please see the demo [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8743819/reducedtestcase/overlaysandclickevents/src/dooverlay.html).

## What I tried and gotten as a result

I tried to do 8 but rule 2 - 7 will be instantly broken.

## What I need

A way to accomodate all 8 requirements without breaking anything else.

## FAQs

1. is this your full app?

No. I did a reduced test case where i stripped out as much un-necessary code to explain my problem without affecting the problem statement as possible.

You can tell by noticing that there is no stylings for the links inside the talk bubbles in the demo.

## Disclosure

1. I have cross-posted this same question at css-tricks.com over [here](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/21193/how-to-assign-different-behavior-to-parent-and-child-elements-when-child-is-hovering-on-top-of-paren#Item_1) to gather greater attention to my problem.

Comment: Can you talk about how you tried to do 8? Or what have you tried?

Comment: @sirhc i have directly used javascript to create a click handler for pageimage-div-overlay. but i have realised that whenever the user clicks on the btn-storysettings, the pageimage-div-overlay gets triggered first. so i am stumped at this point.

Comment: one thought that came to my mind is to rewrite the entire html but i am not sure how to rewrite the entire html while maintaining the other 7 behaviors. i have basically no approach at all to do the rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link below describes how to identify the origin of the click event and execute accordingly.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092675/how-to-cancel-click-event-of-container-div-trigger-when-click-elements-which-ins)

This piece of code seems to work, though I haven't found out why it triggers twice on first load.

```
$(".story-in-myworks").mouseenter(function(e){
    var currentStory = $(this);

    $(this).click(function(e){
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('pageimage-div-overlay'))
            alert('test');

        if ($(e.target).hasClass('btn-storysetting')){
            alert('test2');

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you, @Darkonlore. You have pointed me to the right direction to solve it. I will edit your answer and then mark yours as the correct answer after editing!

Comment: My edit is now queued and will only be visible till it is peer reviewed. So i will mark your answer as accepted first.